# Return value from async / await try..catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have a test folder with files

- file
- file (1)
- file (2)

If the file exists I add a suffix to a new filename, to prevent overwriting the file. For example

- if **file** exists new name should be **file (1)**
- if **file (1)** exists new name should be **file (2)**
- if **file (2)** exists new name should be **file (3)**

and so on.

The following function works fine, except the value is not returned so I can assign it later.

```js
async function dest_exists_new_name(file) {

    const access = fs.promises.access

    try {

        await access(file, fs.F_OK)

        // file exists - generate new name
        const info = path.parse(file)
        const dir = info.dir
        let name = info.name
        const ext = info.ext 

        // generate suffix
        let suffix = ' (1)'
        const suffix_regex = / \([0-9]+\)$/

        if (suffix_regex.test(name)) {              // if suffix exists -> increment it

            const num = name.split(' ').reverse()[0].replace(/[()]/g,'')
            const next_num = parseInt(num) + 1
            suffix = ' (' + next_num + ')'
            name = name.replace(suffix_regex, '')   // remove old suffix
        } 
        // generate suffix end

        const new_name = path.join(dir, name + suffix + ext) 

        // recurse until dest not exists
        await dest_exists_new_name(new_name)

      } catch {

        // file not exist - return its name

        // console.log works OK
        console.log('new name ->', file) 

        // return doesn't work - returns undefined if the previous name exists, but works ok if the name doesn't exists
        return file 
      }
}
```

```js
await dest_exists_new_name('/path/file')

new name -> /path/file (3) // console.log - works OK
undefined                  // returns undefined, if file previously exists
```

The question is how can I correctly return the new file name value?

If there are any culprits in such a solution like

- accidental file rewriting
- infinite recursion
- other issues

I will be grateful for the hints on how to improve the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function **will** return `file`, but being an async function, you need to `await` its return and you cannot do so outside of an `async` scope. Thus, if you just `console.log()` its "istantaneous" value, it will indeed return a pending promise, as the return value has not been resolved yet. You may retrieve the correct return value by including your function in an `async` scope, like this:

```js
let a = async () => {
    console.log(await dest_exists_new_name('/path/file'))
  }

a();
```

This will output:

```js
new name -> /path/file
/path/file //here's your file
```

Now, by adding `return await dest_exists_new_name(new_name)` you should be able to achive what you want and both `console.log()` and `return` the new, *non-existent*, file name. Here's a complete, reproducible example:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

async function dest_exists_new_name(file) {

  const access = fs.promises.access

  try {

    await access(file, fs.F_OK)

    const info = path.parse(file)
    const dir = info.dir
    let name = info.name
    const ext = info.ext

    let suffix = ' (1)'
    const suffix_regex = / \([0-9]+\)$/

    if (suffix_regex.test(name)) {
      const num = name.split(' ').reverse()[0].replace(/[()]/g, '')
      const next_num = parseInt(num) + 1
      suffix = ' (' + next_num + ')'
      name = name.replace(suffix_regex, '')
    }

    const new_name = path.join(dir, name + suffix + ext)

    return await dest_exists_new_name(new_name)

  } catch {

    console.log('new name ->', file)

    return file
  }
}

//Here, make sure that the path to "file" is correct 

let a = async() => console.log(await dest_exists_new_name(path.join(__dirname, './file')));

a();
```

Output, having up to `file (2)` in the same folder:

```
new name -> /path/to/file (3)
/path/to/file (3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! It makes sense. I've added `await` while calling the function, but the function returns `undefined` if the filename previously exists. `console.log` works fine. Could you have a look?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But we do get `console.log` output in the `catch` block when the file doesn't exist. It happens on the last recursive iteration. If we put `return file` in the `try` block it will return the first existing file. But I need to return a non-existent file with the appropriate suffix. Just like in the `console.log` in `catch` close. It outputs `file (3)` which doesn't exist. Check out the function output in my question.

Comment: Looks like it still returns 1st file when testing with `file` name. But if the folder contains files like `file`, `file (1)` `file (2)` it should return `file (3)` which doesn't exist but not `file`. Try to create 3 files on the folder like above and run the function on them.

Comment: Interestingly, that is what I had done, and I get `file (3)` in return. Do you not? Just to be sure, I edited my answer with the complete code I used for the test

Comment: Thanks for the full code. I just give it a try. It still returns `file` for me instead of `file (3)` What node version do you use? I have `v12.8.1` fs.promises.access was added in `v10.0.0`

Comment: I am using `v14.15.4`. So if you try with the full code, it will still console.log `file (3)` but then return `file`? Or is it just both logging and returning `file`?

Comment: I think I found the issue. Try to replace the `path.join` in the `async` function with the full path.  `path.join` works nicely. full path doesn't. I think there is some culprit how the new path is generated.

Comment: Well, indeed, if `access()`  won't access the file , the catch block is immediately activated the input `file` is returned. Well spotted! If I do it like `console.log(await dest_exists_new_name("/full/path/to/file"));` it still works for me though. Maybe you are giving it the wrong full path? If you still use `path.join()` and the relative path you'll get a proper full path as an output. Out of laziness, you could use that one as an input, just to try and see if there were mistakes in the path structure.

Comment: My bad. I typed full path by hand and accidentally missed some `/sub-dir/` :) Thanks for all your help and for the last awesome hint about the permission problem. I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use `await`, since it's async function:

```
        // recurse until dest not exists
        await dest_exists_new_name(new_name)
```

About recursion - IMHO, it's always better to use cycle (if it doesn't make code too complicated).

Mixing async-await & promises is not very good. Ideally you should use one style.

I prefer to use destructuring, lambda functions, and other modern features.

So, my variant for `async-await`, without recursion:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// better to create outside of func, since it doesn't depend on context
const suffix_regex = / \([0-9]+\)$/
const defaultSuffix = ' (1)'

const access = async (...params) => new Promise((resolve) => fs.access(...params, (err) => (err) ? resolve(false) : resolve(true)))

const generate_new_suffix = ({ dir, name, ext }) => {
  if (suffix_regex.test(name)) { // if suffix exists -> increment it
    const num = name.split(' ').reverse()[0].replace(/[()]/g, '')
    const suffix = `(${+num + 1})`;
    const cleanName = name.replace(suffix_regex, '')   // remove old suffix
    return path.join(dir, cleanName + suffix + ext)
  }
  return path.join(dir, name + defaultSuffix + ext)
}

const dest_exists_new_name = async (file) => {
  let newNameGenerated = false
  let newFileName = file
  while (await access(newFileName, fs.F_OK)) {
    console.log(newFileName);
    const info = path.parse(newFileName)
    newFileName = generate_new_suffix(info)
  };

  console.log('new name ->', newFileName)
  return newFileName
}

(async () => {
  console.log(await dest_exists_new_name(path.join(__dirname, 'file')))
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check you try catch and how you are receiving your variable.

```js
async function dest_exists_new_name(file) {
    try {
      const res = await dest_exists_new_name(file1); // recursion result
    } catch (err) {
       return Promise.resolve("file not found");
    }
}

// usage
let res = await dest_exists_new_name(fileArg);
```